# error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const A’ and ‘const A’)

Tags: c++, oop, set, constants, operator-overloading

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> 
class A 
{   
    public:
        A(T a = 0,T b =0): m_a(a),m_b(b) {}

        bool operator<(const A& lhs)
        {
            /* compare code */
        }
              
    private:
        T m_a;
        T m_b;   
};  

int main()   
{
    A<int> abc(2,3);

    set<A<int>> P2D;
    P2D.insert(abc);
    return 0;   
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error

> operand types are ‘const A’ and ‘const A’

If I declare the `const` keyword on the overload `operator<`:

```
bool operator<(const A& lhs) const
{
    /*  compare code */
}
```

It is not giving an error, but:

1. Is there anything I'm missing here?
2. Why is it giving an error if I don't declare the `const` keyword?

Comment: `set` requires its elements to be immutable, because otherwise they might change in a way that invalidates the order of the elements. Therefore it needs to be able to perform a comparison between two `const` `A<int>` objects. If your method had the signature `bool operator<(const A& lhs)`, then that would be saying that `operator<` doesn't modify the (misleadingly-named) `lhs`, but it _could_ modify the actual left-hand argument `*this`.

Comment: It is not clear which difference is giving you an error. Your main snippet has `operator<` const-qualified.

Comment: Separate from that, you have a problem where your `operator<` doesn't actually compare two different `A` objects. It ignores the left hand side completely and then compares one member of the right hand side to another member of the right hand side. So if `foo` and `bar` are both `A<int>` objects, `foo < bar` _only_ depends on the values of `bar`, it doesn't depend on `foo` at all. Is that right?

Comment: Check the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements. Your function does not do  strict weak ordering.

Comment: 1. Yes, `return lhs.m_a<lhs.m_b;` is broken.  2. Because the left-hand side object needs to be `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `operator<` needs to be `const`, because `set` operates on `const` objects internally.

Also, your `operator<` is not implemented correctly anyway.  It is ignoring the members of the `A` object on the left-hand side of the comparison, it is only looking at the member of the `A` object on the right-hand side.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> 
class A 
{   
    public:
        A(T a = T(), T b = T()): m_a(a), m_b(b) {}

        bool operator<(const A& rhs) const
        {
            return ((m_a < rhs.m_a) ||
                    ((m_a == rhs.m_a) && (m_b < rhs.m_b))
                   );
            /* alternatively:
            return std::tie(m_a, m_b) < std::tie(rhs.m_a, rhs.m_b);
            */
        }
              
    private:
        T m_a;
        T m_b;   
};  

int main()   
{
    A<int> abc(2,3);

    set<A<int>> P2D;
    P2D.insert(abc);
    return 0;   
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/JhssAu)